# ElasticSearch Java client based on okHttp

Tags: java, elasticsearch, okhttp, apache-httpcomponents

In my current project I use [Java High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) for ES queries. As my project artifact where I use ES client is AWS Lambda function, I look for ways to reduce the size of the artifact and to reduce memory consumption.

Also as part of improving dependencies usage in this artifact I replaced Apache HttpClient with [okHttp3](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).

But checking transitive dependencies in the project I found that ES Java High Level REST Client use Apache HttpClient. So I decided to find some ES Java client which based on okHttp (or some other lightweight HTTP client which I could use instead of okHttp). I know about different 'non-native' ES clients as [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) or [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) but I don't know any okHttp-based ES client.

Are there any ES clients appropriate to my requirements? Or such optimizations don't have any sense?

Comment: Could you make one with Retrofit?

Comment: @JesseWilson I'm looking for already implemented ES client on top of some lightweight HTTP Java client, but if I will not find anything, I'll write something by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided don't use any special ElasticSearch clients and just use okHttp sending my ES JSON query via POST request.